# Chosen plugin displaying in bootstrap modal not working well

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

What my problem is using chosen display on my bootstrap modal got problem, anyone know what is this problem ?

**here is the screenshot**
[image]

**** Here is my code, I using Codeigniter and Bootstrap framework ****

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal hide fade" id="add_form">
    <div class="modal-header"  style="cursor:move">
        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel" title="drag me around">Add Skill <i class="icon-move" style="margin-top:10px;"></i></h3>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_open('skill/add_skill'); ?>
    <div class="modal-body" style="min-height:400px;">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control">
                    <label for="control-label" class="control-label"></label>
                    <code>Note :</code> All field mark with <code>*</code> are required.
                </div>
            </div><!-- /control-group -->

            <div class="control-group template">
                <label for="input01" class="control-label">Tenant*:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select name="tenant"  data-placeholder="Select Tenant" class="chzn_a span7 ">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <?php if(isset($tenant_records)) : foreach($tenant_records as $row) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row->tenantid; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $row->tenantid; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group  template">
                <label for="input01" class="control-label">Skill*:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="title" name="skill" size="30" type="text"    value="<?php echo set_value('skill'); ?>" placeholder="Skill"  title="Eg: Skill"  />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group  template">
                <label for="input01" class="control-label">Description*:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="title" name="description" size="30" type="text"    value="<?php echo set_value('description'); ?>" placeholder="Description"  title="Eg: Description"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="hidden" name="module_index" id="module_index" value="<?php echo site_url('skill/index/'); ?>" />
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the chosen I used**

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: So I assume the problem is the input width? Try using Chrome Inspect Element or similar to analyze the CSS applied to the input

Comment: Sorry for late reply, even I had set the width, it's still the same

Comment: How did you set the width? I think there are some conflicting styles, that's why using a tool like Chrome Inspect Element will help to check what styles are actually being applied and which are being overwritten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  a `CSS` conflict, may be after adding class `span7` to your `select`.

Try to apply `width` as an **inline style** to the `select`.

```
<select name="tenant" data-placeholder="Select Tenant" class="chzn_a span7" style="width: 200px;">
```

When I used Chosen plugin, I used class as `chzn-select` but you've used `chzn_a`.

**For example:** check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wxz8/1/).

Comment: sorry late reply, the css really conflicted, now its work for me , thanks bro

Comment: @Oscar You're welcome.  Happy to know that you made it to work :)

Answer (score 9):

Apply Chosen after the modal is shown.

```
    $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.chzn-select', this).chosen();
    });
```

Comment: "shown" and "show" are different. i mistakenly type "show" instead of "shown".

Answer (score 2):

Add this css

```
.chosen-container{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.